# Extract CSV data into datagridview after a specific word

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, datagridview

So I have a csv files and I want to extract its data into a datagridview and then save this to a database. I only want it to save data displayed after "Tango N$10 Voucher Benefit,10" (See the CSV file extract to understand) I am using a windows application C#. Here is what I tried so far.

```
try
            {
                var filePath = Path.GetFullPath(openAirtimeFile.FileName);


                foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
                {
                    var thisLine = line;//.Trim();

                    if (thisLine.StartsWith("Tango", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        string[] col = data[0].Split(',');

                        foreach (string s in col)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(s, typeof(string));
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                        {
                            string[] row = data[i].Split(',');
                            dt.Rows.Add(row);
                        }

                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
                    }

                }
```

CSV file looks like this:[image: CSV FILE]

Please help. How do I display data after "Tango N$10 Voucher Benefit,10"?

Comment: So, where is the problem? What is the question? Is it  "I only want" ?

Comment: So how do I display data from that specific point?

Comment: do you want to skip only first three elements from csv? or do you want to skip three elements from each line of CSV?

Comment: Basically, but let's use the clause I specified.

Comment: My best guess would be to first read the csv file in a datatable , and then do a loop skipping the needed columns...It isn't that hard man .. give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a `File.ReadAllLines` two times, so your inner if statement is useless. Perhaps try something like this.

*disclaimer, this only works assuming Tango will be at the start of your csv file*

```
try
{
    var filePath = Path.GetFullPath(openAirtimeFile.FileName);

    bool FoundTango = false;
    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
    {
        var thisLine = line;//.Trim();

            if (thisLine.StartsWith("Tango", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                 FoundTango = true;
                 continue; //Tango has been found, skip to next iteration
            }

            if (FoundTango)
            {                        
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string[] col = line.Split(',');

                foreach (string s in col)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(s, typeof(string));
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] row = line.Split(',');
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
            }

      }
```